# Include jre bundle with .exe created with exe4j tool

Tags: java, exe4j

I have made .exe file using exe4j Tool.But now what i want is to include the jre bundle with .exe.
So can i add this bundle so that no need to install java while running .exe system to system.
I have used exe4j tool  for making .exe file.

Answer (score 0):

You can create [self contained package](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/self-contained-packaging.htm)  to create setup with bundled jre have a look at it.

You can also bundle JRE  yourself by following:
example

1. my jar file is in a dist folder
2. copy the system jre folder to
   dist\jre-win-1.8.0_45
3. create a .bat file with the following line in
   it jre-win-1.8.0_45\bin\java.exe -jar MyProgram.jar
4. Use any free setup maker e.g.[InstallForge](http://www.installforge.net/) to create setup file

Comment: Any other approach??
or can we make  it by using that tool.

Comment: In exe4j we have to add only jar file.
so in this case ...what we have to add????
because now we have three files (.jar , .bat , jre folder)...!!!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using a different compiler use jsmooth for example it doesn'snt have bundling the JRE but it automatically downloads it.